# How to clean TCP Established state sockets?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, tcp

I'm experiencing an issue with my rented VDS server, which is running Ubuntu 22.04. To secure my server, I have enabled ufw (Uncomplicated Firewall) and allowed access only to two TCP ports: `2222` for the SSH server and `8080` for a proxy server.

As part of monitoring incoming connections, I have installed the `tcptrack` application. Initially, everything seemed to be working fine. However, I have noticed a considerable number of irrelevant TCP connection requests originating from IP addresses unknown to me. While most of these requests are properly rejected and closed within a reasonable timeframe, some connections remain in an ESTABLISHED state indefinitely. Unfortunately, this list of persistent connections continues to grow unless I restart my server.

To investigate, I have checked the SSH server logs located at `/var/log/auth.log`, and I have not found any instances of successful authentication, apart from my own (only `publickey` authentication is supported).

I am concerned about the connections that remain in the `ESTABLISHED` state and persistently appear on the `tcptrack` list. I expected these connections to be terminated after a certain period of inactivity. Why do they remain in this state indefinitely, and what impact does the growing list have on my server's functionality? Lastly, is there a way to configure Linux or sshd to automatically terminate established connections if there is no activity?

[image: tcptrack output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've [skimmed the tcptrack source code](https://github.com/bchretien/tcptrack/blob/master/src/TCPConnection.cc#L108), and came to the conclusion that tcptrack does indeed do it's own connection state tracking. What you see is not the same as the state the TCP state machine¹ inside the Linux kernel.

In other words, we don't know whether this display is a bug inside the Linux kernel, which literally powers billions of internet-connected devices, or whether it's just `tcptrack` misinterpreting packets and coming to the conclusion that a connection that's long been in a non-ESTABLISHED state is ESTABLISHED.

I'd assume this is `tcptrack` being wrong, unless profiling your actual kernel network stack tells you you're losing compute cycles to connection tracking. You can test that – stop `tcptrack` and start it anew. Does the same number of ESTABLISHED, but idle for hours, connections still appear?

---

¹ If you want to even call it that – things are [complicated](https://web.archive.org/web/20110719035445if_/http://www.medianet.kent.edu/techreports/TR2005-07-22-tcp-EFSM.pdf).

Comment: ....and/or compare the output of tcptrack and `ss -n4`

Comment: I never suspected from tcptrack. Obviously that was the issue, when I reran the app, they disappeared. Thank you.